# Loading results into the buffer without echoing to the browser

Tags: php, buffer, echo

How can I load loop results into a buffer using the PHP output control functions without echoing the results to the browser? In essence, what I'm trying to do is call results from the buffer as opposed to echoing my way through the loop "as it goes". Is it possible to do this? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not save the output to a variable and simply echo the variable when you're ready?

Comment: "Call results from the buffer"? What does that mean?

Comment: @phpisuber: I'm iterating through an entire array of any particular length, and the output is condition based. It would be impossible to keep track of all the variables. My code would be a mess. I'm looking for a simple way to go about with this.

Comment: What does "condition based" mean? Obviously not `if (something) echo "foo" else echo "bar";` because you would not have asked. Show some code, or give an example.

Comment: @Jon: I want to load the loop output straight into the buffer (without sending the results to the browser) and then output the contents of the **buffer** to the browser.

Comment: @Shmuli You could use a single variable, and concatenate your output to it each iteration. When your loop is finished and your happy, output it with echo. Output buffering has a purpose, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @Jon: Okay, I'll update the question with an example of my code.

Comment: @phpisuber01: That sounds like a good idea and I'll give it a shot. It might resolve the problem without the need for using the output control functions.

Comment: @phpisuber01: Seems that PHP documentation covers how this can be done: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php - as addressed in one of the answers below. Why shouldn't the output buffer be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ob_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to get the buffer contents without sending them.

To clean out the buffer call [ob_end_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)

To do both in one step call [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

An example would be

```
ob_start();
foreach ($results as $result){
     include("tmplate/to/render/a/result.php");
}
$resultHTML = ob_get_clean();
```

Then later.

```
<div class='left-rail'><?= $resultHtml ?></div>
```

Comment: Being the first to answer is good. Being the first to give a *meaningful* answer is much better.

Comment: @Orangepill: Jon is pointing out that it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Shmuli I just thought that with the phrasing of  [output control functions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) he was referring to the functions classified under those names.

Comment: @Orangepill: I was referring to those functions. The question wasn't really regarding their use as much as it was about getting everything into the buffer **without echoing** it to the browser.

Comment: And that what ob_get_clean does... get from the buffer without sending the output

Comment: @Orangepill: But in order to use the output control functions it needs to be output prior. No?

Comment: nope... anything done after ob_start is included everything is buffered until you turn off the output buffer.

Comment: What you are probably used to is the behavior that if you have an open buffer with contents when a php script terminates if flushes them all to the browser... cleaning the buffer will prevent this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31692/discussion-between-shmuli-and-orangepill)

Comment: Thanks so much! Turns out this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

It's still not clear what you mean, but here's an answer based on past experience with php programmers: PHP is a full programming language, so you can build complex data structures without producing any output. If you're reading rows from a database, you can read them into an array, do whatever you want with the array, then produce output when you're ready.

If you're generating output by scanning through the array in lots of steps, you can gradually build up a string (or more, if that's necessary in your case) and again output them when you know what you want to do.

Something along these lines:

```
$output = "";
foreach ($my_array as $row) {
    $output .= "<li>".$row."</li>\n";
    // plus various checks etc.
}
```

Am I getting the idea of what you're after?

Comment: Thanks! That's what phpisuber01 recommended in the above comments. I'll give it a shot; it should do exactly what I'm trying to get at.